# File Not Getting Download Within WebView

Tags: android, url, webview, download

I am working with an android application where i need to open a form URL in my webview. I am able to open the form in webview, there is a submit button with form, click on this button will download the file within webview but its not happening. I am able to download the file with normal browser on mobile like google chrome. How can i download the file within my application webview.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how the you are trying, but you can use this code to download the file inside the webview

```
    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {       

public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
            intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

and add this permission to your android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

hope it will help.!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately its not working. My file getting download if i open the same url with normal browser.